# The user gets logged out upon reloading the page using Firebase as backend

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have built an authentication for my Angular 2 app. I have achieved this by using Firebase authentication service.  Upon reloading the page, the user gets logged out but the token still exists in the localStorage.

This is my code :

```
export class AdminService {

email;
password;
error;
invalidLogin;
isLoggedIn = false;

    constructor(private af: AngularFireAuth,private router: Router,private route: ActivatedRoute) {
     }


      login(){
        this.af.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email,this.password)
        .then(authState => {
          if(authState){
            let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl');
            this.router.navigate([returnUrl||'/']);
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
          }
          else this.invalidLogin = true;
        })
      }

      logout(){   

        this.af.auth.signOut();
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/'])
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The user actually doesn't get logged out. When you reload the page, the Firebase client detects the information in local storage and signs the user in again. Your code just doesn't detect this and thus doesn't route the user correctly.

In the regular Firebase JavaScript client, you'd solve this by [listening for the `onAuthStateChanged()` event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

In AngularFire2 there is a [`FirebaseIdTokenObservable` that exposes an `Observable<firebase.User>`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts#L22). That seems made to do the same, although I admit I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this if you want to use async function

```
  public async getCurrentUser(): Promise<User | null> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        resolve(user);
      });
    });
  }
```

Now you can use it on a guard